# how to print each of the batch file being trained from imageDataGenerator in keras

Tags: keras

I am using Keras ImageDataGenerator with *flow_from_directory*.

For  training data, each class folder has 10,000-20,000 jpg files each, with 13 classes. While training, although keras shows the epoch , I want to print which of the image files are being trained/used in each each batch. How do I do that?

Thanks
sedy

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have a flooding problem, but you can create a wrapping generator:

```
from keras.utils import Sequence

class PrintingGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, keras_generator):
        self.keras_generator = keras_generator

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.keras_generator)

    def __getitem__(self,i):
        x, y = self.keras_generator[i]
        #do the print
        return x, y 

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.keras_generator.on_epoch_end()

generator = PrintingGenerator(original.flow_from_directory(...))
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for the response. is there a way to get this info  from the created generator itself without modifying original generator? if not, this should work and I will try.

Comment: I don't think so...maybe there is but I don't know.

Comment: Daniel, printing x as you suggested prints the image data, not its name.  What ideally I wanted was that as model.fit_generator is executed, and training is displayed each epoch, ideal thing would be to display filenames of each batch, that is being currently used for the epoch.

Comment: Only a custom generator where you load the images yourself then.